# font changes for safari webbrowser

Tags: fonts

**my font style for IE Chrome** 
[other browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4g80.png)
 **for safari it changes**
[safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Ivh.png)

my css

```
body {

    height: 100%;

    font-size: .80em;

    font-family : "PT Sans","Century Gothic",Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: Black;

}
```